# Is there a word for referring to sounds accompagning a company's logo?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWkJ86JqlPA

Is there a word for referring to sounds accompagning a company's logo? The video title is "THX Sound Effect", but it doesn't sound idiomatic, and I doubt it's referred to as "THX Sound Effect" in the company's internal documents, so is there a better phrase or word to refer to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the wikipedia article on [Sound trademarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_trademark), the various sounds associated with a company can be a:

- sound logo (or audio mnemonic)
- jingle
- brand music/theme

The first, "**sound logo**," would probably be exactly the phrase used to refer to this THX sound, however this is not commonly used outside of marketing I think. People would be able to figure out what you mean, but it is not a word that I think most people immediately understand.